# Inserting into MySQL database string but "\n" is getting removed after import

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. I need to pass a string to the MySQL database which has a `\n` in it and I want to save it in the database but it is removing `\n` and replacing it with line break.

PHP code to insert data to the database:

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO pusher_api_holder_v2 (name, text) VALUES ('$site_name', '$text')";
```

Comment: ou are open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even data from the database, [you are still at risk of corrupting your data](https://bobby-tables.com/). If this is a school project. Best time to learn. How to do things right.

Comment: Use prepared statements. The double quotes around the larger sql string is turning `\n` into line breaks. Prepared statements are for more than just SQL injection, it also makes sure your text is inserted the way you want without having to worry about quotes!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement). Frankly it's terrifying how many questions we get here every day where people haven't been taught this kind of basic stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use pdo or mysqli to get rid of for all kind of injections and your text will be inserted as you want it.

You can try this

```
$insert = $db->prepare(”INSERT INTO pusher_api_holder_v2 (name, text) VALUES (?, ?)”);
$insert->execute(array($username,$text));
If($insert->rowCount() >0){echo ”successfully inserted to db”;}else{echo “fail”;}
```